# How to get the width of the dynamic text widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, widget

The fonts of the text in my text widget are dynamic. The width and height of the font change according to different font types. How to get the width or height value of the text widget that varies according to the font.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a GlobalKey into the Text Widget and then check its size somewhere else

```
GlobalKey myKey = GlobalKey();
...

Text('MyText, key: myKey)
```

Then use the currentContext of the GlobalKey to check its size (in a callback after it has been built)

```
print(myKey?.currentContext?.size);
```

But before doing that you need to build the Text Widget

> The current context is null if there is no widget in the tree that
> matches this global key

If you want to know the size it will use before creating the TextWidget you can try creating a TextSpan somewhere (in the initState for example)

```
TextSpan longestParagraphTest = TextSpan(
   text: "This is all my Text",
   style: myTextStyle, //define the style it willl use, fontSize, etc.
);
TextPainter _textPainter = TextPainter(text: longestParagraphTest, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, maxLines: 1)..layout(minWidth: 0.0, maxWidth: double.infinity);
width = _textPainter.width; //This is the width it requires
height = _textPainter.height; //This is the height it requires
```